# How to put an HTML form next to a text?

Tags: html, forms, jsf

Here is my code:

```
Topic one: <h:form> <h:commandButton value="+" /> <h:commandButton value="-" /> 
</h:form>
```

I want the `+` and `-` buttons to be on same line next to the the text `Topic one:`.

Comment: Do you realize that JSF is in the context of this question merely a HTML code generator and that you'd have had exactly the same problem when having `Topic one: <form method="post"><input type="submit" value="+"/></form>`? If so, are you familiar with CSS?

Comment: Thank you, I am not familiar with CSS and I solved with mayabelle's solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a css class like this on your form:

```
.your-class {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your buttons with `<h:panelGroup>`:

```
<h:panelGroup>
    <h:commandButton value="+" /> <h:commandButton value="-" />
</h:panelGroup>
```